# How to insert data from excel into database using php

Tags: php

Hello guys please tell me how to insert excel file into database using php code

Comment: is it real excel or simply csv

Comment: i am new to php am trying.. i am using phpexcel now

Answer (score 2):

You have differents choices here:

1. If you can convert manually this Excel to CSV, do it & simply use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).
2. Else, you can use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know a litte bit more about the structure of the data. One way could be to export a csv and parse/import the file with php.

Answer (score 0):

Upload file to server then read excel file with http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/ and do import to database.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is export the data from excel as CSV so that it can be easier for you to manage ...

you can load CSV directy into MySQL

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/importfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE test_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(field1, filed2, field3);
```

you can also use PHP script such as http://code.google.com/p/php-csv-parser/ to parse your CSV that use mySQL `INSERT` to add the data

I hope this helps

Thanks:

Answer (score -1):

Export it as .csv from Excel then either import it via phpmyadmin or use file_get_contents() and explode() by newline and then by ;.

Comment: If you use CSV, don't use explode!! What happens if you have this : `"asdf,asdf","asdf"`? PHP have 2 nice functions: fgetcsv & fputcsv.

Comment: Did not know about these functions actually. However, excel makes semi-colon separated values and no quotes around strings. You always have to make sure you don't have any unwanted symbols in your data.